# How to use AsyncValue feature when I am using select?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a provider like this:

```dart
@riverpod
class MainProductNew extends _$MainProductNew {
  @override
  AsyncValue<MainProductStateModel> build(String id) {
    return const AsyncValue.loading();
  }

  Future<void> getMainProduct() async {
    final result = await ref.watch(productViewNewRepositoryProvider).getMainProduct(id);

state = AsyncValue.data( state.value!.copyWith(mainProductModel: result.extractDataOrThrow));
  }
}
```

Now in my widget I want to listen to changes for `mainProductModel`. So I am using `select` method.

```dart
   var mainProductState = ref.watch(
        MainProductNewProvider(widget.mainProductId)
            .select((value) => value.value?.mainProductModel));
```

In this scenario I will loose when feature to show loading and error.
How can I use select without loosing `asyncValue` feature ?

I want to use a model as a state and inside this model I have a few models. I want to use it in a few widgets, and these widgets will listen to related models when they are changed the widgets will be rebuilt .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`whenData`](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncValueX/whenData.html):

```dart
var mainProductState = ref.watch(
    MainProductNewProvider(widget.mainProductId)
        .select((value) => value.whenData((value) => value.mainProductModel)));
```

From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncValueX/whenData.html):

> Shorthand for when to handle only the data case.
> For loading/error cases, creates a new AsyncValue with the corresponding generic type while preserving the error/stacktrace.